# Is there a knitr strat for passing R content to LaTeX commands?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm creating a small R package that will allow a user to create exams with R code for tables and figures, multiple question types, randomly ordered questions, and randomly ordered responses on multiple choice items. Inserting R code into LaTeX is not problematic, but one issue I've run into is the need to "slap" together *text* ingested via R with LaTeX commands. Consider this example:

I have this in a LaTeX file:

```
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \item
    {#1}
  \end{minipage}
}
```

I read the content with `readr::read_file` and store it in a variable. I then have the contents of the questions in a .json file:

```
...
    {
        "type" : "mc",
        "section_no" : 1,
        "points" : 2,
        "question" : "What is the best beer?",
        "correct_answer" : "Hamm's",
        "lure_1" : "Miller Lite",
        "lure_2" : "PBR",
        "lure_3" : "Naturdays",
        "lure_4" : "Leine's"
    },
...
```

which I read with `jsonlite::fromJSON` (which converts to a dataframe), do some massaging, and store in a variable. Let's call the questions and their available options `questions`. What I've been doing is putting the necessary LaTeX content together with the character string manually with

```
question.tex <- paste0("\\question{", question[i], "\\\\")
```

to achieve this in the knitted .tex file:

```
\question{What is the best beer?\\A. PBR\\B. Naturdays\\C. Miller Lite\\D. Leine's\\E. Hamm's\\}
```

but I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do this. I'm looking for a function that will allow for a more seamless passing of arguments to my LaTeX command, something like `knitr::magic_func(latex.command, question[i])` to achieve the result above. Does this exist?

Maybe I am asking for an extra level of abstraction that `knitr` doesn't have (or wasn't designed to have)? Or perhaps there's a better way? I guess at this point I'm not far away from being able to create a function that reads the LaTeX command name, number of arguments, and inserts text appropriately, but better to not reinvent the wheel! Also, I think this question could be generalized to simpler commands like `\title`, `\documentclass`, etc.

Small MWE:

```
##  (more backslashes since we need to escape in R)
tex.command <- "\\newcommand{\\question}[1]{
  \\begin{minipage}{\\linewidth}
  \\item
    {#1}
  \\end{minipage}
}"

q <- "What is the best beer?\\\\A. PBR\\\\B. Naturdays\\\\C. Miller Lite\\\\D. Leine's\\\\E. Hamm's\\\\"

## some magic function here?
magic_func(tex.command, q)

## desired result
"\\question{What is the best beer?\\\\A. PBR\\\\B. Naturdays\\\\C. Miller Lite\\\\D. Leine's\\\\E. Hamm's\\\\\\\\"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. As far as I understand your code, the command definition of `\question` is static. You don't need to write this in R and print it into your TEX file; just write it directly into the TEX file (which saves you the double backslashes). To generate the `\question{...text...}` snippets, your `paste0` approach looks reasonable (although you probably forgot a  `}`). To get arguably more readable code, I'd prefer `sprintf`: `sprintf("\\question{%s}", question[i])`.

Comment: See also the `stringr::str_interp` or `glue::glue` for replacing names within the string with values from R variables.